# 'SalesTaxPct' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I am new to C++.  I am struggling with the pass by value thing, and no one can explain what I am doing wrong to me in a way I can understand. I know this is my fault, but Ii am asking for help with my code. HELP PLEASE!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double getValues();
double getSalesTax(double SalesTaxPct);
double gettotal_price(double base, double opt);
void PrintFinal(double base,double opt,double SalesTaxPct);

// function to control all other functions
int main()
{
    getValues();
    getSalesTax(SalesTaxPct);
    PrintFinal(base,pt,SalesTaxPct);
}

// function to calculate sales tax percent into decimal 
double getSalesTax( double SalesTaxPct )    

{
    double SalesTax;

    SalesTax = SalesTaxPct / 100;

    return SalesTax;
}



// function to find total
double gettotal_price(double base, double opt, double SalesTax)

{

    return = (base + opt) * (1 + SalesTax);


}


// function to show user all values input and also total
void PrintFinal(double base, double opt, double SalesTaxPct)

{
    cout << "Base vehicle price: $" << base << endl;

    cout << "Options Price: $" << opt << endl;

    cout << "Sales tax pct: " << SalesTaxPct << "%" << endl;

    cout << "Total vehicle price: $" << gettotal_price(double base, double opt, double SalesTax) << endl;

}


// function to get input values
void getValues()
{
    double base, double opt, double SalesTaxPct;

    cout << "Enter a base vehicle price: " << endl;
    cin >> base;

    cout << "Enter options price: " << endl;
    cin >> opt;

    cout << "Enter a sales tax percent: " << endl;
    cin >> SalesTaxPct;


}
```

Comment: I really like how you have all of your input set aside in one function, and all of your output in another function. This allows you to put all of your main logic in their own code and not care about how you get the result or what you do with it. Some day you may want to get data from a file or send it over a network, and the only thing you have to change is your input / output code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are in `main`, let's go over what the program sees:

```
int main()
{
    getValues();
    getSalesTax(SalesTaxPct);
    PrintFinal(base,pt,SalesTaxPct);
}
```

The only variables that your program knows about at this point are: `getValues()`, `getSalesTax()`, `gettotal_price()`, and `PrintFinal()`. The warning is telling you that at this point of your program, `SalesTaxPct` was not declared yet, and looking at our list of variables / functions that the program knows about, we see that, indeed, `SalesTaxPct` is not on the list. Where do we expect the value of `SalesTaxPct` to come from?

It looks like that comes from the function `getValues`, and we are getting it from user input. However, any time that you have `{ ... }`, the stuff inside the braces cannot be accessed outside. Therefore, `SalesTaxPct` is only "in scope" inside the function `getValues`. If you want it to be accessible outside of that function (which you do), you need to change things around a bit.

```
int main()
{
    double base;
    double opt;
    double SalesTaxPct;
    getValues(base, opt, SalesTaxPct);
    getSalesTax(SalesTaxPct);
    PrintFinal(base, opt, SalesTaxPct);
}
```

Now all of our variables still exist when we need them in `main`. However, there is still a problem here. We want the changes we pass into `getValues` to change the variables in `main`. This means we cannot pass "by value" because that will first make a copy, and then change those copies (not what we want). Instead, we need to say that the changes we make need to be returned from the function some how:

```
void getValues(double & base, double & opt, double & SalesTaxPct);
```

That little `&` there means that rather than making a copy and changing that copy, we are telling the function to operate on the variable we pass in directly. This is referred to as "pass by reference".

There are some similar problems in other parts of your code, but perhaps now you can figure out how to fix them.